# Keep value of File field after form validation with Spring MVC

Tags: forms, spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

I try to do a form involving validators with Spring MVC.

The form contains some file fields but I lose those values if validation fails.

My model attribute contains object of type `MultipartFile`:

```
private MultipartFile docFile;
private MultipartFile pictFile;
```

and the JSP:

```
<input type="file" id="docFile" name="docFile" />
<input type="file" id="pictFile" name="pictFile" />
```

Is there any way to keep those values if validation fails?

Answer (score 1):

You need ModelAttribute...in the controller create ModelAttribute

```
@ModelAttribute("prj")
public ProjektSuche projektSearchForm() {
    if (searchForm == null) {
        searchForm = new ProjectSearch();
    }
    return searchForm;
}
```

and the form has attribute modelAttribute like:

```
<form:form method="get" modelAttribute="prj" action="${urlStartSearch}">
    ...
</form>
```

The **prj** is the name which you choosed from the previous step. The request handler method (same controller) is something like this:

```
public ModelAndView startProjektSuche(@Valid @ModelAttribute("prj") ProjektSuche prjSearch, BindingResult result) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: JSR 303 Validation for the fields of this ModelAttribute

Answer (score 0):

Mulitpart file type objects will never get updated from code. They have to updated only through browse button from user action.